# Any way around putting hidden field in forms for resources with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails by writing simple TODO tasks aplication.
Two models are:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  # ...
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  # ...
end
```

Tasks are routed as a nested resources under Lists. So when a new Task is created by user a `POST` message is sent to `/lists/:list_id/tasks`. So far in `Tasks#new` view's form there is

```
f.hidden_field :list_id, :value => params[:list_id]
```

but it's a terrible solution, because anyone can change value of that hidden field.

**What is the convention here?** Should I put something like

```
@task.list_id = params[:list_id]
```

in `Tasks#create` action and get rid of the hidden field, or maybe

```
@task = List.find(params[:list_id]).tasks.new(params[:task])
if @task.save
  # ...
end
```

or there is even a better way I don't know about?

**Edit:**
Yeah, well there was [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128619/foreign-key-class-id-not-populating-in-belongs-to-association) and its answer is pretty much covering my question. If you have different one please post it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right - that would be horrible. No need for hidden fields. Something like the following.

In your `TasksController`:

```
def new
  @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  @task = @list.tasks.build
end

def create
  @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  @task = @list.tasks.new(params[:task])

  # etc
end
```

In your `Task#new` view:

```
<% form_for [@list, @task] ... %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Didn't know the trick with passing an array for `form_for` but it is in docs, so I know what's what. Great! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about security (like one user creating to-dos in another user's lists - and I assume you are, because you didn't want to use a hidden field stating that `anyone can change value of that hidden field`), I don't see how @bjg solution is any better then yours, since you're getting @list from `params` anyways, and anybody can manipulate params on the browser (changing the URL to post to is as easy as changing the hidden field value).

One common way to solve this without having to implement a more complex permission solution is to just use `current_user` association's, like this:

```
def new
  @list = current_user.lists.where(id: params[:list_id]).take
  @task = @list.tasks.build
end

def create
  @list = current_user.lists.where(id: params[:list_id]).take
  @task = @list.tasks.new(params[:task])

  # etc
end
```

This way, no matter what is the value of params[:list_id] (it could have been manipulated by the user), you can rest assured the @task will end up on that user's account, since @list will only find a record that belongs to `current_user`.

You can evolve this in a real-world app by returning an error message if @list is not found.